# How to smoothen 2D color map in matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, 2d, pixel

My question is if there is any way to smoothen 2D color map using matplotlib? My code:

```
def map():
    # setup parameters
    j = 0
    N = 719
    N2 = 35
    x = np.linspace(190, 800, N) 
    y = np.linspace(10, 360, N2) # (1,2,3), 1 - start Temp, 2- end temp + 10K, 3 - how many steps to reach it
    z = []
    A = np.zeros([35,719]) # [1 2], 1 - number of spectras, 2 - delta wavelength
    # run
    for i in range(10,360,10):
            Z = []
            file_no = (str(0) + str(i))[-3:]
            data = np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\micha_000\\Desktop\\Measure\\' + '160317_LaPONd_g500_%s_radio.txt'%file_no,skip_header = 12)
            for line in data:
                Z.append(line[1]-6000)
            A[j,:] = Z
            j = j+1
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, A, cmap=cm.viridis)
    norm = colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
    plt.xlabel('wavelength [nm]')
    plt.ylabel('temperature [K]')
    plt.title('LaPONd_g500')
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cs, norm = norm)
    plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\micha_000\\Desktop\\Measure\\LaPONd_g500_radio_map.png')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

And here is an example of what i receive:
[image]

Is there any way to make it look better by smoothening pixels transitions?

Comment: I know that `imshow` has an implicity `interpolate` argument, can you do: `plt.show(interpolate='nearest')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the png as an array, and blur it with a mean value filter. search convolution filters to learn more. I've just used a 25 pixel square averaging filter, but you could use a gaussian distribution to make it look smoother..

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage, signal, misc

img = ndimage.imread('C:/.../Zrj50.png')

#I used msPaint to get coords... there's probably a better way
x0, y0, x1, y1 = 87,215,764,1270 #chart area (pixel coords)

#you could use a gaussian filter to get a rounder blur pattern
kernel = np.ones((5,5),)/25 #mean value convolution

#convolve roi with averaging filter
#red
img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 0] = signal.convolve2d(img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 0], kernel, mode='same', boundary='symm')
#green
img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 1] = signal.convolve2d(img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 1], kernel, mode='same', boundary='symm')
#blue
img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 2] = signal.convolve2d(img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 2], kernel, mode='same', boundary='symm')

#do it again for ledgend area
#...

misc.imsave('C:/.../Zrj50_blurred.png', img)
```

Using a gaussian instead is pretty easy:

```
#red
img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 0] = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img[x0:x1, y0:y1, 0], 4, mode='nearest')
```

Comment: @Maq92 If you're going to be doing more with images in the future, I strongly encourage reading up on convolution filters. They're how almost all image processing is done

Comment: This smoothens the data, not the plot. So I would not consider it to be an answer to the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not sure what you're getting at.. I never had access to the data, so all I could do was blur the plot with an image filtering routine. I don't see how your comment adds anything beneficial to the community as a whole. The answer was already accepted, so it was obviously helpful in some way to the OP.

Comment: I think it's common sense to give the reason for downvoting in a comment and that's what I did. Sure this does not help the community, but downvoting without giving the reason is kind of useless.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Which I appreciate, but my argument is that this is just an alternate, and completely valid way of solving the OP's problem. It may not be what you'd do, but the situation didn't necessarily call for changing the way data analysis was being done, only in the way the image was printed.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not the palette (which are all smooth in matplotlib), but that fact that you are using `contourf()`, which generates a finite set of countours, each with a single color, and is therefore not smooth. The default is something like 10 countours.

One quick solution:, increase the number of contour levels  by specifying levels (you can also give an array of which levels to include):

```
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, A, cmap=cm.viridis, levels=100)
```

Better yet, since it seems your data data is already on a grid (e.g. X,Y,Z values for each pixel), you should use `pcolormesh(X,Y,A)` instead of contour to plot it. That will plot with fully continuous values, rather than steps.